# Symfony FosRestBundle - Hyphenated rest routes

Tags: fosrestbundle, symfony

I'm currently learning the basics of the FosRestBundle in a basic Symfony 3 project and am looking at creating a hyphenated REST route.

An example of a simple route I currently have, where `GET /coffees` hits `CoffeeController::getCoffeesAction()` as expected;

```
coffees:
  type: rest
  resource: ApiBundle\Controller\CoffeeController
```

I'm now looking at creating another rest controller to represent a coffee pot, so URLs follow a format like `GET /coffee-pots` to hit `CoffeePotsController::getCoffeePotsAction()`. I've tried every key I can think of whilst referencing the docs (`"coffee-pots"`, `coffeePots`, `coffee_pots` etc) and I only ever get a 404. The rest of the configuration is correct, since if I change the key and action to just `pots` it works fine.

I have successfully implemented routing annotations within the Controller (e.g. `@Get("/coffee-pots", name="get_coffee_pots")`) but I'd rather avoid that unless it's a particularly bad practice to do so.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I just ran into this. From the console, type the following to list all of your routes:

```
php app/console debug:router
```

It will likely be at `/coffeepots`.

Comment: I know what my current URL is, the question was how to generate hyphenated URLs. For what it's worth I've built another API with Symfony and had a lot more joy with API Platform than the FOS bundle.

Comment: When I came across this, I was also looking to do hyphenated URLs. I dug into the FOS bundle and it doesn't look like it is possible unless you set a custom route for each action. I bailed and went with unhyphenated. Unhyphenated is the [standard for fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Cloud_APIs_REST_Style_Guide#URL_Style) for what it's worth. I'll have to check out API Platform, thanks!